# Storing a bytestring in python dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, binary

I am trying to use a dictionary store byte strings.

```
COMMANDS = { 'Serial': b'\x40'}
```

Calling 'Serial':

```
print(COMMANDS['Serial'])
>> b'@'
```

I know this is the ASCII representation, however I later want to use this to calculate checksums and the conversion adds a layer of complexity. Is there a way to store the data without it being changed, or a way to call the data differently?

Comment: `b'\x40' == b'@'`. It is still a byte string, and `ord('@') == 0x40`. Just use it the same way as you would before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to store the data without it being changed

There is no "conversion", only [representation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr).  **Your data is not being changed**.  So, simply, don't worry about it.

It is quite common for objects to have literal syntaxes which are non-unique, yet these are parsed and represented into a unique form.  Here's another example:

```
>>> 42.
42.0
>>> 42.000
42.0
```